# Android Spinner validation

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I need to validate *selected item* of `Spinner` in `Android`.

I tried the following code, but it's not working.

```
if (Spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim() == "Pick one") {
    Toast.makeText(CallWs.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

What is wrong with the code, and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.equals` or `.equalsIgnoreCase` to compare two strings in `java/android` instead of `==`.

Try this

```
if (Spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("Pick one")) {
    Toast.makeText(CallWs.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `equals("Pick one")` and always use [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method when checking for *equality* for `String` type in *Java* (unless you are checking for ***reference*** equality) as follows;

```
if (Spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("Pick one")) {
    Toast.makeText(CallWs.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

What's wrong with you code is; you are using `==` which results in checking if `Spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString()` is the *same reference* as `"Pick one"` which will always be false since "Pick one" is a `new String()` *instance*

For details, check:

- [string .equals() vs ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)
- [How to compare Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this.

```
else if (Spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Pick one")) {
            Toast.makeText(CallWs.this, "Error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Never try to compare two strings using == operators. Its bad thing for programming to compare two strings.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new layout called spinner_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

inside your activity MainActivity.java initialize your spinner view:

```
Spinner mySpinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.items_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Finally use the following method to validate your spinner:

```
boolean validateSpinner(Spinner spinner, String error){
        View selectedView = spinner.getSelectedView();
        if (selectedView != null && selectedView instanceof TextView) {
            TextView selectedTextView = (TextView) selectedView;
            if (selectedTextView.getText().equals("")) {
                selectedTextView.setError(error);
                Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean validateSpinner(Spinner spinner, String error){

    View selectedView = spinner.getSelectedView();
    if (selectedView != null && selectedView instanceof TextView) {
        TextView selectedTextView = (TextView) selectedView;
        if (selectedTextView.getText().equals("Select Academic Year")) {
            selectedTextView.setError(error);
            Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```